# LESS: Subtract from variable

Tags: css, less

Using LESS, how can I subtract values with "px" at the end of the variable. I have the following variable:

```
@bpMobile: 600px
```

What I want to do is subtract this by 1px

```
@media only screen and (max-width: @bpMobile - 1px ) {
}
```

How can I achieve this with LESS?

Comment: Just tried that, didn't seem to work.

Answer (score 35):

Sorry for answering this late, but I had this very problem and it seems LESS is picky about the spacing. You also need `()` around your calculation.

**This will not work:**

```
@media screen and (max-width: (@widthSmall-2)) { }
```

**However, this will** (notice the space between the variable and the digit):

```
@media screen and (max-width: (@widthSmall - 2)) { }
```

Comment: Well, of course Less is picky about spaces since `-` can be a part of an identifier in CSS. E.g. we don't expect `max-width` to substract `width` from `max`. As for parens for `@media` query values - yes, they are required regardless of `--strict-math` option.

Answer (score 11):

You can always use the [`calc function`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=CSS%2Fcalc) for this.

Syntax:
`calc(expression)`

Eg:

```
abc {
  width:calc(100%-20px)
}
```

[Here](http://caniuse.com/#feat=calc) are the list of browser that supports this function

**EDIT 1:**

you can use it in the following two ways:

LESS Input:

```
@bpMobile: 600px;
max-width: calc(~'@{bpMobile} - 1px');
```

CSS Output:

```
max-width: calc(600px - 1px);
```

2nd Way:
Less Input:

```
@bpMobile: 600px;
max-width: calc(@bpMobile - 1px);
```

CSS Output :

```
max-width: calc(599px);
```

With the first option,the calc arguments are escaped in order to prevent them from being evaluated on compilation.The values will remain totally static until it's evaluated by the client.

With the second option, the calc value will be evaluated on compilation. And it would be the same as

```
max-width: @bpMobile - 1px;
```

which will result in

```
max-width: 599px;
```

Comment: Can I use this with variables though? Like calc(@bpMobile - 1px) ?

Comment: calc is not supported with media queries

Comment: The first solution would be horrible, even if it did work: After all, both values (@bpMobile and 1px) are known at less-compileTime, so the 2nd Way should be it! – Having said that: still good, that you point the „right escaping“ out for scenarios, where this is not possible, i.e. `height: 100vh - @someHeightInPx`, where a runtime `calc()` (=readable in the css) is the only option…

Answer (score 4):

The fix from freejosh does not work for me on lesscss 1.7.0.

What does the trick is simply adding paranthesis around every variable or calculation inside a media-query:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: (@bpMobile - 1px) ) { ... }
```

or

```
@other: @bpMobile - 1px;
@media only screen and (max-width: (@other) ) { ... }
```

Comment: The bottom solution worked for me.  The key is to space out everything exactly as shown and to add parentheses around the variable in the media query.  I am using LESS 2.3

Answer (score 3):

The problem isn't the math function, it's that you're trying to use it in a media query. [The docs](http://lesscss.org/#-media-queries-as-variables) say that you need to make the whole query one variable:

```
@bpMobile: 600px;
@bpMobile1: @bpMobile - 1px;

@singleQuery: ~"only screen and (max-width: @{bpMobile1})";

@media @singleQuery {
}
```

Comment: I think that URL has now changed to http://lesscss.org/features/#features-overview-feature-operations

Answer (score 0):

————————————————————————————————

In my case .

```
      .loop(@i) when (@i > 0) {
        @index : @i + 1;

        .abc_@{i}{
          z-index : @index;
        }

        .loop(@i -1);
      }
      .loop(8);
```

will give output:

```
.abc_8{
  z-index : 8 + 1;
}
```

————————————————————————————————

Another case :

```
      .loop(@i) when (@i > 0) {
        @index : pow(@i,1) + 1;

        .abc_@{i}{
          z-index : @index;
        }

        .loop(@i -1);
      }
      .loop(8);
```

will give output:

```
.abc_8{
  z-index : 9;
}
```